SwiftUI App Not Updating on UserSessionManager State Changes
I'm developing a SwiftUI app that uses a UserSessionManager to handle authentication state. The UserSessionManager is stored in a dependency container and injected into the app via an environment object. However, my UI is not detecting state changes on the UserSessionManager and updating accordingly, even though I've confirmed that the state is changing (through didSet logging).
Code Structure
DependencyContainer
class DependencyContainer: ObservableObject {
    let apiService: any APIServiceProtocol
    let authService: any AuthenticationServiceProtocol
    let userService: any UserServiceProtocol
    let sessionManager: any UserSessionManagerProtocol
    
    init() {
        apiService = APIService()
        authService = AuthenticationService(apiService: apiService)
        userService = UserService(apiService: apiService)
        sessionManager = UserSessionManager(authService: authService, userService: userService)
        apiService.setTokenProvider(sessionManager)
    }
}

App Initialization
@main
struct GatherApp: App {
    @StateObject var container = DependencyContainer()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(container)
        }
    }
}

ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var container: DependencyContainer

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                switch container.sessionManager.authenticationState {
                case .initial:
                    ProgressView { Text("Loading...") }
                case .unauthenticated:
                    LandingView()
                case .authenticated(let signupStep):
                    if signupStep == .completed {
                        HomeView()
                    } else {
                        SignUpFlow(currentStep: signupStep)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

UserSessionManager (partial)
class UserSessionManager: UserSessionManagerProtocol {
    @Published var authenticationState: AuthenticationState = .initial
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    // ... other implementation details ...
}

What I've Tried

I've confirmed that the authenticationState in UserSessionManager is changing by adding didSet logging.
I've made sure that UserSessionManager conforms to ObservableObject and its properties are marked with @Published.

Question
Why isn't my UI updating when the authenticationState in UserSessionManager changes? Am I missing something in how I'm propagating these changes through my app's structure?
Additional Information

Xcode Version: 15.0.1
iOS Target Version: 17
Swift Version: 5.9

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You can’t nest ObservableObjects. You can try Observable

This isn't valid SwiftUI. ObservableObject is for storing model data, not for managers/controllers. For your controllers its best to use structs and put them in an EnvironmentKey so they can be mocked for previews. Fyi .task replaces @StateObject and you can call your controller async funcs directly from there.

@malhal thanks for the headsup. Do you know of any material that covers this sort of design pattern?

Nesting ObservableObject like you do (UserSessionManager inside DependencyContainer) is not a good idea. With nested ObservableObject the inner one does not trigger the outer one view to update. You need to manually do that yourself.
Restructure your code to have one single source of truth UserSessionManager
that is passed to other views. Note that class DependencyContainer: ObservableObject
does not @Published... anything, hence will not observe anything.
